# namespace declaration issue

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, xslt-1.0

I am trying to remove namespaces declarations from transformed xml

Please go here: http://xslttest.appspot.com/

input xml:

```
<Products xmlns="http://api.company.com.au/Data" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Product>
<Code>BM54</Code>
</Product>
</Products>
```

xslt template

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:d="http://api.company.com.au/Data" exclude-result-prefixes="d">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="d:Product">
        <DONE>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </DONE>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@Product">
        <xsl:attribute name="DONE">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is:

```
<Products xmlns="http://api.company.com.au/Data" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<DONE xmlns="">
<Code xmlns="http://api.company.com.au/Data">BM54</Code>
</DONE>
</Products>
```

I want it to be:

```
<Products xmlns="http://api.company.com.au/Data" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<DONE>
<Code>BM54</Code>
</DONE>
</Products>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change

```
<xsl:template match="d:Product">
    <DONE>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </DONE>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="d:Product">
    <xsl:element name="DONE" namespace="http://api.company.com.au/Data">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Note that this isn't "removing namespaces" -- you're actually putting the `DONE` element _into_ the correct namespace for it to inherit the default from its parent. What it's doing is avoiding the need to cancel the inherited default. That's what was asked for in the sample output, but isn't what the original poster thought they were asking for.

Comment: if you read at the bottom of the post, the OP laid out his requirement. May be the OP wants to say "I am trying to remove unwanted namespace declaration from some nodes in the transformed xml".

Comment: Agreed, @JoelM.Lamsen -- My intent was to clarify, not criticize. Apologies if it came across as the latter.

Answer (score 1):

The alterate solution, if you want to created elements into the default namespace is to declare that upfront:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:d="http://api.example.com.au/Data"
     xmlns="http://api.example.com.au/Data" 
     exclude-result-prefixes="d">
<!--  rest of the document -->
```

This makes the shorthand of `d` and the *empty namespace* both correspond to `http://api.company.com.au/Data` which is what you were intending, even if it isn't what you asked.

Then you can use the original code:

```
<xsl:template match="d:Product">
    <DONE>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </DONE>
</xsl:template>
```

As keshlam pointed out, this works becuase you are putting it into the same namespace as the rest of the document.